# Should I disable Addictive Drums native effects when using Pro Tools?

Tags: drums, mixing, protools

I'm working on some videos of myself recording at home. It doesn't need to sound professional but good at least. My setup is Pro Tools, Addictive Drums and some instruments. I'm wondering if it'd be more effective disabling the AD FX totally sending on pre-fader and apply the EQ Compressor on Pro Tools. I feel like it's just worth if I master drums mixing.

Comment: Try both - see what sounds best for you. That is really the only way to choose - some people would keep it, others would disable...